# Validate EF Code first model against existing database

Tags: ef-code-first

Is there a way to check that a DbContext matches the database when the database was not created by EF code first?

I am looking for similar functionality to [Database.CompatibleWithModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.compatiblewithmodel%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) but there is not metadata.

Answer (score 7):

There is currently no way in EF to do this; however, you may be able to use the DDL script as a starting point for verifying that all the artifacts exist in the database. To get this script, use

```
string ddlScript = ((IObjectContextAdapter)myContext).ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript();
```

Some tools may be able to use this script to do a schema compare against your database. This will tell you if your model is compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d).

> you can use the tools to Reverse Engineer Code First - Generates POCO
>   classes, derived DbContext and Code First mapping for an existing
>   database.

And then maybe you can compare the reversed engineered information with what you already have.